# Cannot read property 'getHours' of null

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am following this vue/vuex/firebase tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fls6uX7WWSs&list=PL55RiY5tL51qxUbODJG9cgrsVd7ZHbPrt&index=21 ,and I am currently stuck with the vuetify date and time pickers.  I keep getting this error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of null"

I have tried several solutions posted here and other places like using .toISOString().substr(0, 10) to convert the date and time to a string and i get this error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <h4>Create a new Meetup</h4>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <form @submit.prevent="onCreateMeetup">
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-text-field name="title" label="Title" id="title" v-model="title" required></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-text-field
                name="location"
                label="Location"
                id="location"
                v-model="location"
                required
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-btn raised class="primary" @click="onPickFile">Upload Image</v-btn>
              <input
                type="file"
                style="display: none"
                ref="fileInput"
                accept="image/*"
                @change="onFilePicked"
              >
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <img :src="imageUrl" height="150">
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-textarea
                name="description"
                label="Description"
                id="description"
                v-model="description"
                required
              ></v-textarea>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <h4>Choose a Data & Time</h4>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row class="mb-2">
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-date-picker color="primary" v-model="date"></v-date-picker>
              <p>{{date}}</p>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-time-picker color="primary" v-model="time"></v-time-picker>
              <p>{{time}}</p>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
              <v-btn class="primary" :disabled="!formIsValid" type="submit">Create Meetup</v-btn>
              <p>{{submittableDateTime}}</p>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </form>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      location: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      description: "",
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      time: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      image: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.title !== "" &&
        this.location !== "" &&
        this.imageUrl !== "" &&
        this.description !== ""
      )
    },
    submittableDateTime() {
      const date = new Date(this.date)
      if (typeof this.time === "string") {
        let hours = this.time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]
        const minutes = this.time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]
        date.setHours(hours)
        date.setMinutes(minutes)
      } else {
        date.setHours(this.time.getHours())
        date.setMinutes(this.time.getMinutes())
      }
      return date
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCreateMeetup() {
      if (!this.formIsValid) {
        return
      }
      if (!this.image) {
        return
      }
      const meetupData = {
        title: this.title,
        location: this.location,
        image: this.image,
        description: this.description,
        date: this.submittableDateTime
      }
      this.$store.dispatch("createMeetup", meetupData)
      this.$router.push("/meetups")
    },
    onPickFile() {
      this.$refs.fileInput.click()
    },
    onFilePicked(event) {
      const files = event.target.files
      let filename = files[0].name
      if (filename.lastIndexOf(".") <= 0) {
        return alert("Please add a valid file!")
      }
      const fileReader = new FileReader()
      fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.imageUrl = fileReader.result
      })
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
      this.image = files[0]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want a format that will be submit-able to firebase like 2019-02-18T23:20:38.950Z that comes from the submittableDateTime computed function.  Thanks for the halp!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string like `2019-01-01` to `v-time-picker`. It should be a `Date` object

You can change your init data

```
 data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      location: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      description: "",
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      time: new Date(),
      image: null
    }
  }
```